# xmpp client with server ejabberd

Tags: client, xmpp, ejabberd, pidgin, wokkel

I am using ejabberd as server and want to deploy it on a large scale. Can you suggest me the client best suited so that I can plug it in seamlessly. I am thinking of using wokkel or pidgin but not really sure of the best possibility. Any sort of guidance will be appreciated.

Actually my complete requirement is development of a chat engine - including server, clients etc. Currently I am working on things at my desktop only but once done, I have to host it; basically incorporate it with in a site for chatting purpose. So, now my problem is:

I am not clear about how the actual data flow is? I have googled and read about xmpp (a book by Peter Andre) also but I am not clear about the flow and what are the actual requirementsto do the above mentioned task. What I currently know is:

1) I need a server - so selected ejabberd

2) I need client - still not sure which one to use and one other doubt is how this client thing will work when deployed on some website for chatting purpose.

3) Some library - dont know which one and what is the purpose?

Comment: You want to write a component that connects to ejabberd or connect to it with a desktop client?

Comment: @ggozad: Improved the actual question.

Comment: Your [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/227127) was rejected, since you made it while logged out; I've edited it in for you.

Comment: If a web-based chat app is what you want to build then the most popular client-side library in js is https://github.com/metajack/strophejs.

Answer (score 1):

2) You can use a web client like Candy Chat (uses Strophe IIRC)  http://candy-chat.github.io/candy/

3) Create your own webclient using javascript and the Strophe library which ggozad mentioned.